# How to properly branch to earlier actions in the flow of an activity diagram?

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram, activity-diagram

I am trying to design an activity diagram for an app that does some text summarization. This is what I have so far:

[image: user activity Diagram]

I tried searching for some advice, but couldn't figure out where I should connect the arrow after the user said no to logout.

Comment: I dared to make the title somewhat more general, so that other people having similar problems -- whatever their app is managing -- can benefit too.  If you think, the description is inaccurate, don't hesitate to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct. As you use a [decision node](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node) to select the yes/no alternative, you should merge the alternative flow back with a [merge node](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#merge-node) (diamond).

Moreover, your [join node](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#join-node) at the top would never work, because a join node needs all its inputs to be activated (i.e. a token must be present on each).  In your case, it would wait forever.

Fortunately, the correction is simple: replace your top join (first bar) with a merge (diamond)

***Additional hint: UML activity is not flow chart***

- The decision node only helps to chose the path and does not perform any action on its own; labels yes/no should therefore be guards the fully express the condition (e.g. `[users wants to logout]`) and any interaction with the user should happen in a previous action (e.g. `Propose logout to user` or `Propose choices for next actions`)
- Same remark for `Error encountered` and `Retry`.
- Hidden trap:  `Click generate summary button` has two incomning arrows.  While in traditional flowchart, you'd think that one or the other is sufficient for the flow to continue,  in UML activity diagram, the multiple incoming flows is like an implicit join:  all must present a token for something to happen.  Here as well,  you should redirect the two incoming flows to an additional merge node which then has one outgoing arrow that should be the sole incoming arrow of your action.

Comment: The 'Click generate' would stll hang.

Comment: @qwerty_so true.  addressed as well. Took me a little longer to spot it ;-)